# Set and Declare - passing a column content -

Tags: sql, set, declare

I have seen the following statement online which solves 80% of my problem, but I need to pass a column through this process and not just setting a standard date as shown below 
(SET @Date = '25032014';).

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(8); -- input parameter
SET @Date = '25032014';

DECLARE @Date2 CHAR(10);
SET @Date2 = STUFF(STUFF(@Date, 3, 0, '/'), 6, 0, '/');

SELECT @Date2, CONVERT(DATE, @Date2, 103); -- 103 = dd/mm/yyyy
-- 25/03/2014     2014-03-25
```

would appreciate the answer, as I am going mad here - I am sure an easy one to answer

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: HI - I did tag it as SQL

Comment: SQL is a language specified by ISO/ANSI. What you've got there is some product specific implementation with some non-standard extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert that to a select statement, assuming a table MyTable and the column you want to operate on MyDate

```
DECLARE @Date2 CHAR(10);
SET @Date2 = STUFF(STUFF(@Date, 3, 0, '/'), 6, 0, '/');
```

would become

```
SELECT STUFF(STUFF(MYDate, 3, 0, '/'), 6, 0, '/') AS date2 
FROM MyTable
```

The last query could be written using a subquery

```
SELECT date2, CONVERT(DATE, date2, 103) from (
  SELECT STUFF(STUFF(MYDate, 3, 0, '/'), 6, 0, '/') AS date2 
  FROM MyTable
) as tbl
```

Comment: HI Ian Kenny - many thanks for answering this. Perfect - Thanks